# Print df in python class

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to print `spark_df`dataframe without rerunning the entire query. In the first step I am running the `run_query` function and print the df and in the second step I would like to print `spark_df` by accessing `new_df` that has been saved in memory to avoid re-running the entire query.

I added the following code snippet after the `pandas_to_spark` function but I none is returned

```
report = DataPipeline()
DataPipeline.pandas_to_spark(report)
print(report.spark_df)
```

```
class DataPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_df = None 
        self.spark_df = None
        
    def run_script(self):
        self.run_query() #return new_df in memory 
        self.pandas_to_spark()

   def run_query(self):
        """ Run query  """
        query = '''select * from table'''
        query = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn_lake)
        new_df = query.fillna('NaN')
        self.new_df = new_df 
        return self

   def pandas_to_spark(self): 
        """ Function to convert pandas df to spark df """
        mySchema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True)
                               , StructField("customer_id", StringType(), True)])
        new_df = self.new_df
        spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_df, schema=mySchema)
        self.spark_df = spark_df 
        return self 


report = DataPipeline()
DataPipeline.run_query(report)
print(report.new_df)
```

Comment: Does `pandas_to_spark` belong to your class? Why there is an unindented code snippet between the class definition and supposedly a class method? Can you properly edit the code?

Comment: yes it does, just edited the code

Comment: run_query() works and returns new_df but I am trying to return spark_df by not re-running the entire query. I was hoping that since new_df is saved in memory that there should be a way to run the pandas_to_spark function and access new_df

Comment: OP says `none is returned` for `print(report.new_df)`. Am I getting it right that now `run_query() works and returns new_df` ?

Comment: yes thats correct

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the job. You've got everything you need in the class, and you just need to call the `run_script` method of the `report` object:

```
report = DataPipeline()
report.run_script()
print(report.spark_df)
```

**EDIT:**

If you insist to run this first:

```
report = DataPipeline()
report.run_query()
print(report.new_df)
```

then you can do

```
report.pandas_to_spark()
print(report.spark_df)
```

without initializing the class again. Otherwise the new_df will be wiped.

Comment: this would re-run run_query function. Since new_df is saved in memory I thought there should be a way to run run_script without re-running the query again

Comment: @user12625679 no it doesn't re-run run_query function. what makes you think it re-runs? try to add a print statement inside run_query and I'm pretty sure it's only printed once only if you run my code.

Comment: @user12625679 just to clarify, you don't need to do `run_query` in the bottom part of your code. Just define the class, and then put my code below the class.

Comment: @user12625679 also see my edited answer, if you insist to do runquery first, and then convert to spark